# AWS AnonymousTVM Compiling Java Server Side

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have downloaded to AnonymousTVM server side code in java from http://aws.amazon.com/code/8872061742402990. My problem is I need to change something in the code but don't know how to compile it in order to create a new .war file. I appreciate a little help. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ant command(using build.xml file) in version 1.2.0 doesn't compile the java codes. it just packes the needed files for your .war file. It seems like version 1.3.0 has been changed and it's ant compiles the whole package.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=111850&tstart=0